# looping an arraylist with a for each doesen't do anything

Tags: java

First of all, sorry for bad English-

I want to move from "Ventas" to "Historico" only the objects that has the samen code than "codCli" from "Clientes", this is my code:

```
public static void Eliminar_Cliente(){

        System.out.println("Que cliente quieres eliminar? (Introduce el código de cliente)");
        int cliE=(sc.nextInt()-1);

        Cliente clienteBuscado=null;

        for (Cliente cliente : cli) {
            if(cliente.codCli==cliE) clienteBuscado=cliente;
        }

        if(clienteBuscado!=null)
        {
          ArrayList<Ventas> ventaAux=new ArrayList();

          for (Ventas venta : vent) {   
              System.out.println("asddsa");
              if (venta.cliente==clienteBuscado.codCli){
                  Historico h = new Historico(venta);
                  his.add(h);
                  ventaAux.add(venta);
              }
          }

          if(!ventaAux.isEmpty())
          {
              for (Ventas ventas : ventaAux) {
                  vent.remove(ventas);
              }
          }

        }

    }
```

but the ouput is absolutely nothing, it doesn't even enter the Ventas' for each loop.

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like `clienteBuscado` is `null`. What's the content of `cli`?

Comment: Where is `vent` defined?

Comment: Just my 5 cents, please do not write programs in native language.

Comment: Add extra println statements inside the first loop to ensure that clienteBuscado is assigned to something. And add another one to print out the size of vent (let's hope it's not zero!).

Comment: Donde defines vent y his?

Comment: I have a method to fill `vent`, and it works, i cheked it.

Comment: `vent` y `his` están definidos más arriba `ArrayList<Ventas> vent=new ArrayList<Ventas>();` y lo mismo para `his`.

Comment: @MG_Bautista Please write in english even in comments - aunque yo os entienda, no significa que todos puedan!

Comment: Move this line `System.out.println("asddsa");` after `if (venta.cliente==clienteBuscado.codCli){` and run again, the problen can be the condition in te `if`.

Comment: I moved it, but still doing nothing :(

Comment: You say: "but the ouput is **absolutely nothing**". You don't even have the first message "Que cliente quieres eliminar? (Introduce el código de cliente)"? If not, you're not executing the `Eliminar_Cliente()` method.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i got that message, but not the others :S

Comment: Be sure that `cli` is not an empty collection and that it contains the client code you are looking for. If it doesn't contain it, then `clienteBuscado` will be null and you won't pass the `if(clienteBuscado!=null)` condition, as @Reimus told you in his answer. Add `println()` statement to ensure that.

Comment: Finally solved by fixing this `if((cliente.codCli-1)==cliE) clienteBuscado=cliente;` thanks for all your help people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, the `Collection` `vent` is empty. Ensure that the Collection is populated correctly prior to invoking `Eliminar_Cliente`.

Also if `clienteBuscado` is `null` the `if` statement block where the `for` loop is invoked will never be entered -> ensure that `clienteBuscado` is assigned a value.

And more fundamentally make sure you're actually invoking `Eliminar_Cliente`.

Aside: Java naming conventions use *camelCase* for method names, for example `eliminarCliente`

Comment: I tried with this

    ArrayList<Ventas> ventaAux=new ArrayList(vent);

But it doesn't worked neither

Comment: If `vent` is empty then doing that wont have any effect, you'll still get an empty `List`. Check how youre populating `vent`